# Can I convert a Rawsignature to PKCS#7 in xcode using Openssl

Tags: iphone, openssl, pkcs#7

I could susscessfuly genearte pkcs7 signature using PEM(private key)file in Openssl.
But, how do I convert a RAWsignature generated using security.framework to pkcs7 using Openssl.

Edit: 
load data > load PEM(private key)file > generate pkcs7 data using Openssl ....this is successfull

but

Load private key (SecKeyRef) from keychian > (how to pass this key to OPenssl to generate Pkcs7)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IOS doesnt have feature to generate PKCS#7 Signature. We have to use OpenSSL with no other Alternative I suppose.

And IOS protects the keys using KEYCHAIN it provides. So the SecKeyRef is only a readable and not transferable. Better dont ever try to write to some file or transport it.

IOS features can generate only PKCS#1 Singnatures.

And if the RAWSignature is genereated using a PKCS#12 file, PKCS#7 singature can be generated out of it, using Bouncy Castle...server side....

did it... and it works... :)

Comment: would you please share your solution using boucy castle , i have exact same problem and badly stuck in that